# Data frame of name against anova summary

Tags: r, dataframe

*Apologies if this has been answered before, but I find it very difficult to get answers for my R problems!*

My problem relates to how I can store the results of multiple anovas in a useful way.

I am performing anovas on subsets of a data frame using 'aov', comparing two data frames at a time, using the below function:

```
doAnova = function(first, second) {
    aov(number ~ factor1+factor2, data=rbind(first, second))
}
```

This is used to compare each subset against a 'base' case, to check for significant differences. To perform this over the multiple datasets, I use it in a loop:

```
for (name in names) {
    result = summary(doAnova(base,subject))
}
```

I want this result to be stored in a data frame with each row containing the 'name' and the 'result' values.

So far I have tried both storing lists and vectors of the names and results, and then trying to create data frames from those, but haven't managed to get this right.

I know this is probably pretty simple, but anyone able to help solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing an end-around on the more standard practice of analyzing all the data and then doing post-hoc testing to examine subset comparisons. Statisticians would generally consider this to be unprincipled data dredging. Also the help page for `aov` says :

## "Note

`aov` is designed for balanced designs, and the results can be hard to interpret without balance: beware that missing values in the response(s) will likely lose the balance."

So I think you should be coding your subsets  with identifying factor variables and using the facilities that R provides for analysis of unbalanced designs, namely `lm` . Only after you have examined the estimated effects in a global fashion should you be turning to appropriate *post-hoc* tests that allow a principled correction for the multiple comparisons issues.

Comment: Given that each subset is already identifiable by such a variable (currently used to subset them) this is likely what I should do. Unfortunately statistics isn't a strong suit of mine so I'm not entirely clear- what makes a design balanced/unbalanced? I'll look into `lm` as an alternative

Comment: I have 1 'normal' condition and 40 varied conditions of my independent, with 50 rows for each, each then with values for 13 independent variables. This matches that description of balanced doesn't it? Also, before I partake in more "unprincipled data drudging", do you have any hints of appropriate tests over the whole data in this case?

Comment: The "40 varied conditions" needs to be better spelled out, and it seems unlikely that "13 independent variables" can allocate equally among the 40 "conditions". It sounds as though you should be discussing a mixed model where these 40 conditions will be random effects and the 13 variables are your fixed effects for which you desired inferential judgements. That is a job for a statistician, but you can often attract good responses by posting such questions on stats.stackexchange.com or on the R mixed models mailing list: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models.